# Support two versions of a python package without clients needing to change code

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to support multiple versions of a python package without impacting client code.

Consider the following repo:

```
.
|-- client_code.py
`-- lib
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- foo.py
```

**client_code.py**:

```py
from lib.foo import f
...
f()
```

I'd like to leave `client_code.py` unchanged. I first tried to do something like this:

```
lib
|-- __init__.py
|-- v1
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- foo.py
`-- v2
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- foo.py
```

**lib/__init__.py**:

```py
import os

if os.environ.get("USE_V2", "0") == "0": # Or some other runtime check
    from .v1 import foo
else:
    from .v2 import foo
```

But the client code fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client_code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib.foo import f
ImportError: No module named foo
```

I'm aware that the following options would work, but they would require clients changing code:

```py
if os.environ.get("USE_V2", "0") == "0":
    from lib.v1.foo import f
else:
    from lib.v2.foo import f

f()
```

```py
if os.environ.get("USE_V2", "0") == "0":
    import lib.v1.foo as foo
else:
    import lib.v2.foo as foo

foo.f()
```

Is something like this possible?

A more general version of the question is here: [Support two versions of a python package without clients needing to change code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67994542/support-two-versions-of-a-python-package-without-clients-needing-to-change-code)

Comment: Add foo to `__all__` in v1 and v2 init files

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Thanks for reading and offering your help. I tried adding `from . import foo; __all__ = ["foo"]` to both `__init__.py` files, but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to impact anything. The error seems to be suggesting that `lib` doesn't have the module named `foo`. (Note that I get the same `ImportError` even if I do `from .v1 import foo` in `lib/__init__.py`)

Comment: I'm not much of a dev, but why not publish multiple versions of the lib instead of packaging v1 and v2 together?

Comment: @wjandrea Great point. I normally would. However, for my use case, v1 and v2 have to do with different runtime environments: CPU architectures (v1=x86, v2=arm), CUDA versions (v1=CUDA10, v2=CUDA11), python versions (v1=py27, v2=py3), etc. The submodules include multiple pybind shared objects which are built in different environments and linked against different libraries. The code can run on a heterogeneous compute cluster, where machines have different capabilities based on the type of task that needs to be run (training/evaluating a model, loading datasets, etc.) or cloud GPU availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the most elegant, but this seems to work.

```
├── client.py
└── lib
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── foo.py
    ├── v1
    │   └── foo.py
    └── v2
        └── foo.py
```

#### foo.py

```
import os
if os.environ.get("USE_V2", "0") == "0":
    from lib.v1.foo import *
else:
    from lib.v2.foo import *
```

#### v1/foo.py

```
def f():
    print("I'm v1.f")
```

#### v2/foo.py

```
def f():
    print("I'm v2.f")
```

#### client.py

```
from lib.foo import f

f()
```

#### Running output:

```
$ env | grep USE_V2
USE_V2=1
$ python client.py
I'm v2.f
$ unset USE_V2
$ python client.py
I'm v1.f
```

Having the actual **foo.py** `import *` looks bad, but it's just the lazy approach.  Given a v1 and v2 contents that were somewhat different, you could have foo.py *adapt* the imports to present an uniform API in both cases.  Or you could say prepare a `functools.partial` version of a V1 function that doesn't exist in V2 anymore.

`__init__.py` is empty and doesn't even need to exist under Python 3.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely answers the question I asked. Unfortunately, I probably over-simplified. Any thoughts on how to have this work for an arbitrary package layout under `lib`? In other words, it would be nice to also support `from lib.bar import g` and `from lib.baz import h` without having to write `bar.py` and `baz.py` (which are effectively identical to `foo.py`).

Comment: hmmm.  not sure.  the __init__.py behavior of packages might be used.?  that's several levels too dynamic **and** module-savvy for me to say.  I can say one thing though:  past a certain point dynamic runtime systems become very hard to reason about.  you have to think long and hard before building that type of architecture.

Comment: but at another level, instead of having lib/foo.py resolve versions, maybe lib.py can do that?

Comment: :-) Funny that you mention that. I immediately tried that after reading your solution, but I ran into the same problem. You can see it with your solution when the client code has `from lib.foo.bar import f`. This will not work unless you also create `lib/foo/bar.py` to handle the indirection to `lib/v{1,2}/foo/bar.py`. Maybe the `so` motivation described above in response to @wjandrea provides more clarity on the challenge I'm facing.

Comment: @JKD I can only answer the question you asked, not the unspoken more complicated requirements behind it.  I **think** one way to avoid too much knowledge about the library code structure *could* be to avoid deep imports:  instead of `from lib.foo import f` use `import lib` then call `lib.foo.f()`.  That leaves more freedom to arrange dynamic code loading by either `lib.__init__` or `lib.foo`.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll accept your answer and post a new question with the more complete ask. Thanks for the help!